# Network Analyst for QGis or another Open Source Geographic Information System?

Tags: network-analyst

Im looking for alternative ways for analyse my network dataset.
So, there is another way to analyse an GIS network? I mean if there are any useful plug-in capable to determine service areas, routes, or even VRPs like Arcmap does? Road Graph plugin can do all this stuff?

Answer (score 4):

Use [PgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/).  PgRouting works with PostGIS and so it falls into your category of "another OS GIS".  Underdark has created a whole suite of tutorials (including installation instructions) [here](http://underdark.wordpress.com/tag/pgrouting/).  A search on this site for pgrouting will generate a lot of other discussion, links and tips.